# Cannot connect my Moto E in USB mode to the Linux system

Tags: android, linux, motorola, usb-drive

I'm using Moto E and my laptop OS is Linux. To do data transfer, I'm trying to connect my Moto E to my laptop in USB mode, but I could not.

Whereas, the connection in USB mode is flawless with the Windows system.

Can anybody help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

For the Moto E, I connected it to the computer, then enabled USB debugging.  Open the terminal and load up nano or vim and create a new configuration file in the udev rules:

`sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`

input the below string and save the file:

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"`

make the file readable ;

`sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`

back in the phone, disabled USB debugging, unplug the phone and plug it back in.

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

you have to add your device to a list described in above link